# How to read facebook graph json data using python?

Tags: python, django, facebook, json, facebook-graph-api

When I print "user_stream" in the development environment, the full string gets printed.  However when I view what gets printed in the console in the production environment, the full contents of "user_stream" is not printed, which I believe is leading to an error later on in additional code I have.

My question is: why aren't all the contents of "user_stream" being printed in the console in the production environment and how do I fix this?

```
instance = UserSocialAuth.objects.get(user=request.user, provider='facebook')
token = instance.tokens
user_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=" + token['access_token']

u = urllib.urlopen(user_url);
user_stream = json.loads(u.read())

print user_stream
```

Comment: Try printing the u, just to make sure that it is working correctly.

Comment: This is what I get when I print u: <addinfourl at 139662821688384 whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x7f05c903b750>>

Comment: I meant `u.read()`, should have been more specific, sorry...

Comment: Now I just see "[error]" with no additional text.  I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this because when I copy/paste the user_url with the access token into the browser, I'm able to see the full json.

Comment: Do you see the error from user_stream, or the print out of `u.read()`?

Comment: I have print u.read + print user_stream.  I see the error coming from u.read.  I still see the partial json being printed from print user_stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error in your user_stream somehow. The best way to figure out what it is is to either print the string, or print the error message directly. These commands should help you figure out what is going on.

```
print u.read()
print user_stream['error']
```

I strongly suspect that your access token isn't valid somehow. Look into that as well. An example of what you might see from the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me/friends?access_token=AAACEdEose0cBAM0CipLFjIDZCysqmGyZCRJ6x4JsdSVkb177lM0UNMWqSYZA9BmBY0h3PbUiIJppQCbDZD) is this:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Malformed access token AAACEdEose0cBAM0CipLFjIDZCysqmGyZCRJ6x4JsdSVkb177lM0UNMWqSYZA9BmBY0h3PbUiIJppQCbDZD",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 190
  }
```

Read the message there carefully, and see if you can figure out how to correct it. Also, try printing our your full URL and running it in the Graph API Explorer.

Comment: When I do print u.read(), I simply see "[error]".  When I do print user_stream['error'], I get an error saying KeyError for 'error'.  I also thought that the access token wasn't valid too, but when I visit https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=AAACksif9DeoBAADTs6KQ6rBZCgRpgZB6UIRgZBG6LMoG0LHi80h17iPeQkmhhOzkkIZBaBt08FpnL7ZBJZBrBUxZB7PIOLrHTkZD (which includes the current/correct access token), I'm able to see the full json with no error.  Any advice?